# gsub and returning the correct number in a string

Tags: r, gsub

I have a text string in a data frame like the following

`2 Sector. District 1, Area 1`

My goal is to extract the number before `Sector` or else return blank.

I thought the following regex would work:

```
gsub("^(?:([0-9]+).*Sector.*|.*)$","\\1",TEXTSTRINGCOLUMN)
```

This correctly returns nothing when the word `Sector` is not present, but returns `1` rather than `2`. Greatly appreciate help on where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a regex lookahead for "Sector", capture the numbers as a group and in the replacement specify the capture group (`\\1`).

```
sub('.*?(\\d+)\\s*(?=Sector).*', '\\1', v1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "2"
```

EDIT: Modified based on @Avinash Raj's comment.

Without using the lookarounds, (credit to @Avinash Raj)

```
sub('.*?(\\d+)\\s*Sector.*', '\\1', v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "2 Sector. District 1, Area 1"
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for cases when `Sector` is not present - e.g. `x <- c("2 Sector. District 1, Area 1","Nothing")`

Comment: @thelatemail `str_extract(x, '(\\d+)(?=\\s*Sector)')` returns NA for that

Comment: @thelatemail Looks like the OP's initial code return `''` for those.  I am not really sure where the OP's code is failing.

Comment: @akrun wait... won't work for `23 Sector`, your regex must be `'.*?(\\d+)`

Comment: no, need for Perl, `sub('.*?(\\d+)\\s*Sector.*', '\\1', v1)` :-)

Comment: enable perl, `str_extract(v1, perl("\\d+(?=\\s*Sector)"))`

Comment: @AvinashRaj In the new stringr version, wrapping with perl is not needed. as it gives me warning `perl is deprecated. Please use regexp instead`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
x <- "2 Sector. District 1, Area 1"
substring(x, 0, as.integer(grepl("Sector", x)))
#[1] "2"
```